# Optimized way to find index pairs of two values in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of predictions on text data which gives a column named "prediction". here is the code to recreate it.

```
import pandas as pd  
# initialize list elements
data = ['others', 'others', 'prediction1', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'prediction2', 'others', 'prediction2', 'others', 'others', 'prediction1', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'prediction2', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'prediction1', 'others']
score = [0.75, 0.75, 0.9, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.88, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.9, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'prediction': data,
     'score': score
    })
```

I want to find a list of index pairs of `[(index_prediction1,index_prediction2),(index_prediction1,index_prediction2)]` in this column where when prediction1 is found, find next prediction2 which has score higher than 0.85 and similarly find more pairs like this. prediction1 has no restriction of score.

Currently I'm using iterrows which I came to know are very slow. This is my current code for finding all pairs.

```
pred_pairs = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row['prediction'] == 'prediction1'):
        for index, row in df.iloc[i+1:].iterrows():
            if row['prediction'] == 'prediction2' and row['score']>=0.85:
                pred_pairs.append((i,index))
                break
pred_pairs
```

I would like to know a better approach to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### original question

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
pred_pairs = list(zip(df.index[df['prediction'].eq('prediction1')],
                      df.index[df['prediction'].eq('prediction2')]))
```

Output:

```
[(8, 20), (28, 36)]
```

Or, if the pairs always alternate, with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
out = (df.index[df['prediction'].isin(['prediction1', 'prediction2'])]
         .to_numpy().reshape(-1, 2).tolist()
      )
```

Output: `[[8, 20], [28, 36]]`

##### updated question: more complex logic

- only keep the prediction2 > 0.85
- keep the first prediction2 after each prediction1

```
s = df.query('(prediction == "prediction1") | ((prediction == "prediction2") & (score > 0.85))')['prediction']

out = [list(x.index[:2]) for _, x in s.groupby(s.eq('prediction1').cumsum())]
```

Output: `[[2, 12], [15, 23], [28]]`

If you only want the pairs in which there is a prediction2:

```
s = df.query('(prediction == "prediction1") | ((prediction == "prediction2") & (score > 0.85))')['prediction']

out = [l for _, x in s.groupby(s.eq('prediction1').cumsum())
       if len(l:=list(x.index[:2]))>1]
```

Output: `[[2, 12], [15, 23]]`

Comment: is it possible to add 1 more condition to this on top of eq=prediction1 , there is a score column and I want to keep it >0.85. Basically prediction2 have multiple values in a column and I want the one which score > 0.85. Sorry I forgot to add that in question

Comment: Sure, please update the question with the details, but most likely you need to filter with `df.query('score > 0.85')`

Comment: it is not fixed that 1 more prediction2 cant come in between two pred1. that's why I had to go for a loop based approach. Sorry I didnt mention this before.

Comment: Then please also provide different examples and show what output you expect if you have one or more or no intermediates ;)

Comment: yeah sorry my bad :). I edited now. Basically if a pred1 is found then find next pred2 having score >0.85.  score of pred1 doesn't matter.  Also there could be times at the bottom when no pred2 is present after pred1, in this case loop just skips that part.

Comment: For example if you have `P1a, P2a, P1b, P1c, P2b, P2c`, which ones should be mapped together? I'd say P1a+P2a, P1b+P2b and ignore the others, no?

Comment: p1c will never come before p2b. there are multiple p2 in between two p1s. but never vice versa. p1 is like pivot point and I have to find a p2 in between two p1s where score>0.85. So in case if this happens: P1a,P2a,p2a,p1b,p2b,p2b,p1c,p2cp2c, I want pairs of (p1,p2) when p2>0.85

Comment: Have a look, if this is still not what you're looking for please provide several **short** examples (no need for many "other", just 1 or 2)

Comment: second solution works well for me! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `pandas.cut` to match the indices of *"prediction1"* with a suitable interval built on the indices of *"prediction2"*:

```
pred_1 = df.query('prediction == "prediction1"').index
pred_2 = df.query('prediction == "prediction2" & score >= 0.85').index

answer = pd.DataFrame({
    'prediction1': pred_1,
    'prediction2': pd.cut(pred_1, [0, *pred_2]).rename_categories(lambda x: x.right)
})
```

Given the data example from the original post, we obtain the following answer:

```
   prediction1 prediction2
0            2          12
1           15          23
2           28         NaN
```

The type of *"prediction2"* is categorical, which can be transformed into numeric either with `pandas.to_numeric` or `.astype` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = ['others', 'others', 'prediction1', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'prediction2', 'others', 'prediction2', 'others', 'others', 'prediction1', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'prediction2', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'others', 'prediction1', 'others']
score = [0.75, 0.75, 0.9, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.88, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.9, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'prediction': data,
     'score': score
    })

pred1_indices = df.index[df['prediction'] == 'prediction1']
pred2_indices = df.index[df['prediction'] == 'prediction2']

pairs = []

for pred1_index in pred1_indices:
    relevant_pred2_indices = pred2_indices[pred2_indices > pred1_index]
    relevant_pred2_indices = relevant_pred2_indices[df['score'].values[relevant_pred2_indices] >= 0.85]
    if len(relevant_pred2_indices) > 0:
        pairs.append((pred1_index, relevant_pred2_indices[0]))

print(pairs)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).